# past simple or present perfect

Tags: tense, tense-agreement

Please have a look at this sentence:

> We **haven't gotten** a lot of Finnish groups that we **liked** here at Bananas but I'm pretty happy with this four tracker from Helsinki, apparently recorded in the same place where the Ramones played in the 70's.

The first verb is in present perfect (up to now) and the second is in simple past tense. I don't understand the simple past for the second verb.

Why "like" is not in its present perfect form as the first verb is?

Comment: What is the source of the sentence ? Can you give a little more context ?

Comment: it is a review of a finnish record

Comment: Is this a full sentence? There's no period at the end of it.

Comment: We haven't gotten a lot of finnish groups that we liked here at bananas but I'm pretty happy with this four tracker from Helsinki, apparently recorded in the same place where the Ramones played in the 70's.

Comment: I haven't ever seen *have/has liked* in sentences. I don't think it's wrong but perhaps rarely used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We haven't gotten *a lot of* Finnish groups that we liked...

obviously refers to a period of time including the present, so *haven't gotten* is fine.

> ...Finnish groups that we liked...

The decision (whether liked or not) seems to be made when each individual group was at Bananas, so each decision would be made at a specific time in the past. So simple past is fine.

Comment: even  if the decision continues in the present....