# Why is the past simple used in this sentence?

Tags: tense, tense-agreement

> We haven't gotten a lot of Finnish groups that we **liked** here at Bananas but I'm pretty happy with this four tracker from Helsinki, apparently recorded in the same place where the Ramones played in the 70's.

I know my question has already been answered. **liked** is past simple because it is a single action. But I don't agree with it or have not well understood  the answer.

*'Bananas'* is a music magazine. Every time they receive a record they make a review(like it or not) so this is not a single action and maybe in the future there will be some Finnish band they will like. It may change !!!

Comment: Is the first paragraph a quote?

Comment: Then why did you accept the answer for the same question you posted :http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/76838/past-simple-or-present-perfect ?You should only accept an answer if you truly got your question answered.